# How to implement join operation on two collections in mongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb

My database has been designed exactly like SQL. One collection is referenced by another by using primary key. This key is also stored in second collection. I want to join these two collection in MongoDb? How to implement this

Answer (score 0):

You would query the "master" collection (the one with the references) for the documents you want first, also loading the references, and then query the other collection according to those referenced and needed documents. So you do need two queries.

You can also use an ODM like Doctrine, which will automatically help you keep track of the references, as long as they are mapped.

http://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/reference-mapping.html

Scott